# json data not shown in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Html Code is :

```
<select  name="ser" id="ser" class="form-control" onchange="getPrice(this.value);">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option value="Value11">Value1</option>
<option value="Value2">Value2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="sale" id="saleprice"  class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="sale" id="saletax"  class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="sale" id="avalqty"  class="form-control" />
```

on my Js Page :

```
function getPrice(val)
{
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'get_sales_price.php',
     data: {
       get_option:val
     },
     success: function (response) {
        var valuesar = response.split("|");
        $('#saleprice').val(valuesar[0]);
        $('#saletax').val(valuesar[1]);
        $('#avalqty').val(valuesar[2]);
     }
   });
}
```

This is my PHP Page Data:

```
$data = array();    
$values=$variable1['value1'].'|'.$variable2['value2'].'|'.$variable3;
array_push($data, $values);
echo json_encode($data);
```

The value on `#saleprice` is : **["61.25** and the value on `#avalqty` is : **155"]** and the value on `#saletax` is : 1. `#saletax` value is correct..
How to get `#saleprice`  : **["61.25** to **61.25** and `#avalqty` : **155"]** to **155**

Comment: try console.log(response) in ajax success and post here what you get.

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is to return a `key-value` object from the server and use that in the success handler. In your case you are returning a array with a single string value

```
$data = array();    
$data['price'] = $variable1['value1'];
$data['tax'] = $variable2['value2'];
$data['qty'] = $variable3;
echo json_encode($data);
```

then

```
function getPrice(val) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'get_sales_price.php',
    data: {
      get_option: val
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      $('#saleprice').val(response.price);
      $('#saletax').val(response.tax);
      $('#avalqty').val(response.qty);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: how to append a list box in above php code as array value.

Answer (score 0):

try JSON.parse(response) in your success function.
You are sending your string in an array, so you need to parse it first, access the string using array index and then split this string. Otherwise, you can simply echo the string directly in your php code, rather than pushing it in an array and then using json_encode.

So your php code should be

```
$values=$variable1.'|'.$variable2.'|'.$variable3;
echo $data;
```

This way you will receive a string in your ajax response, which you can split directly.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`var valuesar = response.split("|");` to

```
 var valuesar = response[0].split("|");
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can use your code in following way

```
<?php
$data = array();    
$values='6.15'.'|'.'52.22'.'|'.'55.25';
array_push($data, $values);

$rr=json_encode($data);


$ltrim = ltrim($rr, '["');
$rtrim = rtrim($ltrim, '"]');


// echo $rtrim;



?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {


var response='<?php echo  $rtrim ?>';
console.log(response);

var valuesar  = response.split("|");


$('#saleprice').val(valuesar[0]);
$('#saletax').val(valuesar[1]);
$('#avalqty').val(valuesar[2]);

 console.log(valuesar[0]);

 });

 </script>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="saleprice" id="saleprice" >
<input type="text" name="saletax" id="saletax" >
<input type="text" name="avalqty" id="avalqty" >
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```